# Example Registers for 2" x 12" Duct

Tags: hvac, flooring, vent

I am new to DIY Stack Exchange as well as home renovations in general so I will do my best to be concise and provide adequate clarity for my question, without sounding overtly inexperienced.

I had a contractor install some new wood floors in my house awhile back, and they left pretty large gaps around the floor ducts. Because of this, the old registers no longer fit as there is now a gap between the register and the edge of the hardwood floor.

The duct size is 2" x 12", but the overall size of the gap the floor provides is 3 7/8" x 15". The subfloor "hole" is less than this but the new wood floor recedes further than the subfloor.

Are there floor vents that will fit this (seemingly) unconventional size? Is this even an unconventional situation to size a floor vent for? Anything I find isn't exceeding 13.5" total (top face) width or 3" depth.

Comment: As a shopping question this is off topic. Taking the tour would help you understand the format.

Comment: I don't take this as a shopping question, they are not asking which is the best item or the quality of a specific brand, they are asking a general question about sizing and standard fit.

Comment: I am not interested in specific brands and am not looking to "shop". I want to know if the dimensions I am requiring are abnormal or if there is something else I am overlooking when analyzing what dimensions are required. If they are abnormal, I am hoping to ascertain whether or not the contractor screwed up to the point where I need it reinstalled, or if there is another (hopefully simpler) fix out there.

Comment: You can also use a flush mount wood register. Has a fairly large frame and you would need to cut the floor to drop it in. Google "how to install flush mount vent into an existing floor". Sounds like the flooring installer screwed up and you may be able to get him to correct his mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the Shormaker Co. makes several styles of custom floor grilles/registers.

https://www.shoemakermfg.com/Product-Finder/Line/Residential/Type/Register

I’d contact them and they can tell you how to measure for correct fit. They only have a few finishes, but the quality is great (but not cheap).  Let them know if you expect a heavy load on the registers.